# After Upgrading to Magento 2.4.6-p3, minicart does not update with Ajax add to cart

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.6

After upgrading Magento from 2.4.6-p1 to 2.4.6-p3, ajax add to cart does not update minicart. There is no error in console or var/log files.

Comment: Please check your custom module and custom theme, I suggest disabling checkout related module and changing the theme to default and check it.  if you have more error or error log please share them.

Comment: disabled all 3rd part extensions, luma theme , no console no exception on system log